# Creating Drop Down Menu Nav- HTML/CSS Bella Beauty

Tags: html, css, format, dropdown, nav

So I'm currently trying to make a dropdown menu for my horizontal navigation. I want all three buttons to look the same but when hovered over the 'Products' in nav I would like it to display the three product categories "Contour" "Eyebrows" and "Lips" as a dropdown to then click on and take me to the their individual pages.

I've tried a range of things but it never works or keeps to the formatting of the navigation I want now so it doesn't look consistent.

Can anyone help me create one? Below I will attach the HTML and CSS for the Home page.

```css
/*Bella Beauty Logo*/
h1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 15%;
}

/*Navigation*/
#navBar {
  display: inline;
  padding: 1000px 170px;
  font-family: Cinzel;
  font-color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17pt;
}

/*Showcase/Hero Image*/
#HeroImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
}

/*Showcase/Hero Text*/
#BannerText {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*Showcase/Hero Shop Button*/
.ShopNowbtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 115%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #D8F9FF;
  color: #d604ac;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-family: Cinzel;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/*Showcase/Hero Title Text*/
#Welcome1 {
  font-family: Cinzel;
  font-size: 25pt;
  color: #D8F9FF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #d604ac; 
}

/*Showcase/Hero Desc Title*/
#Welcome2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 19pt;
  color: #D8F9FF;
}

#header {
  background-color: #D8F9FF;    
}

#content {
  background-color: white;
}   

/*Business Journey Part 1- Title*/
#BeginTitle {
  font-family: Cinzel;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22pt;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #d604ac;
}

/*Business Journey Part 1- Description*/
#BeginDesc1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19pt;
}

/*Business Journey Part 1- Description*/
#BeginDesc2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19pt;
}

/*Business Journey Part 1- Picture*/
#BeginPic {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/*Business Journey Part 2- Title*/
#CreationTitle {
  font-family: Cinzel;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22pt;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #d604ac;
}

/*Business Journey Part 2- Description*/
#CreationDesc1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19pt;
}

/*Business Journey Part 2- Description*/
#CreationDesc2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19pt;
}

/*Business Journey Part 2- Picture*/
#CreationPic {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 450px;
}

/*Business Journey Part 3- Title*/
#LocationTitle {
  font-family: Cinzel;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22pt;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #d604ac;
}

/*Business Journey Part 3- Description*/
#LocationDesc1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19pt;
}

/*Business Journey Part 3- Description*/
#LocationDesc2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19pt;
}

/*Business Journey Part 3- Picture*/
#LocationPic1 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 47%;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

/*Business Journey Part 3- Picture*/
#LocationPic2 {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 47%;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

/*Business Journey Part 4- Title*/
#OpenTitle {
  font-family: Cinzel;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22pt;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #d604ac;
}

/*Business Journey Part 4- Description*/
#OpenDesc1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19pt;
}

/*Business Journey Part 4- Description*/
#OpenDesc2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19pt;
}

/*Business Journey Part 4- Picture*/
#ShopInterior {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/*Map & Opening Hours Border*/
#Border {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  outline-style: dotted;
  outline-color: #d604ac;
  outline-width: 3px;
}

/*Interactive Map*/
#Map {
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  
}

/*Bella Beauty Opening Hours*/
#OpeningHours {
  display: block;
  font-family: Cinzel;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

/*Social Dimensions*/
.Socials {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

/*Facebook Icon*/
#Facebook {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

/*Instagram Icon*/
#Instagram {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

/*Twitter Icon*/
#Twitter {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F1FDFF;
  color: black;
  font-family: Cinzel;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!--Linking Google Font- Cinzel-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <div id="header">
    <!--Bella Beauty Branding Logo-->
    <h1><img src="Bella Beauty Logo.png" alt="Bella Beauty Logo"></h1>
    
    <div id="nav">
      <!--Navigation Bar-->
      <ul>
        <li id="navBar"><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li id="navBar"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li id="navBar"><a href="Staff.html">Staff</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Header-->
  <div id="content">
    <div id="Banner">
      <!--Showcase/Hero Image-->
      <img id="HeroImage" src="Banner.jpg" alt="Bella Beauty Banner">
      <!--Text and Button over showcase image-->
      <div id="BannerText">
        <p id="Welcome1">Welcome</p>
        <p id="Welcome2">to Bella Beauty, a thriving local salon in the heart of Belfast</p>
      </div>
      <button class="ShopNowbtn">Shop Now > </button> 
    </div>
    
    <!--Journey To Business Part 1-->
    <div class="Beginnings">
      <p id="BeginTitle">Where It All Began</p>
      <p id="BeginDesc1">At the point when Claire was only 18 she began doing her friends makeup for all the events you could imagine, from intense Prom looks to sentimental date looks, she truly could do everything!</p> 
      <p id="BeginDesc2">The more she did, the more people she had asking her to their makeup...they where even willing to pay!</p>
      <img id="BeginPic" src="BeginPic.jpg" alt="Claire beginning as a makeup artist">
    </div>
    <!--Journey To Business Part 2-->
    <div class="Creation">
       <p id="CreationTitle">Bella Beauty Is Created</p>
       <p id="CreationDesc1">Claire enjoyed doing young womens makeup so much and empowering women around her she chose to transform it into a business!</p>
       <p id="CreationDesc2">Claire began by making the name 'Bella Beauty' after the word 'Bella' signifying 'Beautiful' in Italian. She felt it said a lot about the business she wanted to create by making young women beautiful by enhancing their finest facial features not covering them up!</p>
      <img id="CreationPic" src="CreationPic.jpg" alt="Claire creating Bella Beauty">
    </div>
    <!--Journey To Business Part 3-->
    <div class="NewLocation">
       <p id="LocationTitle">Bella Beauty Comes To Belfast</p>
       <p id="LocationDesc1">The time had come to get a premises and Claire fell in love with Belfast. After a long hunt and heaps of viewings she at last chose a highstreet space outside the esteemed 'Victoria Square'.</p>
       <p id="LocationDesc2">A space on the highstreet gave Claire the ideal opening to many customers strolling by while building was in progress and the word began to get out about a brand new beauty shop coming to town!</p>
      <img id="LocationPic1" src="LocationPic1.jpg" alt="Victoria Square">
      <img id="LocationPic2" src="LocationPic2.jpg" alt="Bella Beauty Under Construction">
    </div>
    <!--Journey To Business Part 4-->
    <div class="BusinessOpen">
       <p id="OpenTitle">Bella Beauty Opens For Business</p>
       <p id="OpenDesc1">After a considerable delay with development and lots of time spent ensuring everything looked perfectly like Claire's vision...she opened, sold her first item and extended her team to three staff!</p>
       <p id="OpenDesc2">Bella Beauty is now a bustling business offering a range of cosmetics items to start young makeup artists and amateurs to return home and start on their journey into the art of makeup and maybe one day, a customer will follow in Claires footsteps.</p>
      <img id="ShopInterior" src="ShopInterior.jpg" alt="Inside Bella Beauty">
    </div>

<!--Map & Opening Times-->
  <div id="Border">
    <div id="Map">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1155.6432572904432!2d-5.927957941836744!3d54.59894504885941!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48610855d362c579%3A0x5385d89154488f3a!2s5-19%20Ann%20St%2C%20Belfast%20BT1%204EA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1605143571609!5m2!1sen!2suk" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="OpeningHours">
      <p>Monday-Friday: 9am-4pm</p>
      <p>Saturday: 9am-6pm</p>
      <p>Sunday: Closed</p>
    </div>  
  </div>

<!--Footer with Social Media Links-->
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="Socials">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/studyatulster/">
      <img id="Facebook" src="Facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
      </a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/UlsterUni?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor">
      <img id="Twitter" src="Twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ulsteruni/?hl=en">
      <img id="Instagram" src="Instagram.png" alt="Instagram">
      </a>
    </div>
    <p>Bella Beauty - Copyright 2020</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was learning to code I learned a lot from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)
In your case I would like to refer to this page:

https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_dropdowns.asp

The method described does not require any JavaScript to work

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is way away from drop down menu. it seems that you have not added the :hover property or you are not familiar with some CSS properties So here's the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHFflWvii3M from where you can learn drop down menu
if it helps let me know.